# If the given function is of bounded variation.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, bounded-variation

Let  $f:[0,1]\rightarrow R$   be a  function  defined  by

$ f(x)= 0 $ if  x  is  irrational
$f(x)$=${1}\over {q^{2}}$ for $x$=${p}\over{ q} $  where  $p$  and  $q$  are  relatively  prime

$f(0)=0$
 $f(1)=1$

Then  is  $f$  of  bounded  variation$?$

If  I  take  partitions of  the  interval $[0,1]$ as  $\{x_{0},x_{1},.......x_{n}\}$  such  that  $x_{i}$  is  irrational for  odd  $i$ and  rational  for  even  $i$. Then $\sum_{1}^{n}|\Delta f_{k} |$=$\sum_{i=1}^{[n/2]}$ ${1}\over {q^{2}} $.Now  taking  limit $n\rightarrow \infty$  this  series  is $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}$${1}\over {n^{2}}$ which  is  convergent  hence  bounded  by  some $M$$\in R$. So  by  definition  of  bounded  variation  this  function  is  of  bounded variation. Am  I  correct? But I  did not use  the  definition  of  $f$  at  $0$  and  $1$  .

Comment: The value $\frac{1}{q^2}$ is attained multiple times (for $q > 2$), so you can't bound the variation by $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$. In fact, $f$ has unbounded variation.

Comment: Then  can  I  prove  this  is not  of  bounded  variation? How ? nSome  lead  please .

Comment: If $p$ is a prime, how often does the value $\frac{1}{p^2}$ appear?

Comment: p-1  times . So  this is  $(p-1)\over p^{2}$=$1\over p$ $-$ $1\over{p^{2}}$

Comment: Right. And if you sum that up ...

Comment: So  I  get $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $1\over {n}$ $-$  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}$ $1\over {n^{2}}$  and  the  left  side  does  not  converge. So  unbounded  variation. Is  that  right?

Comment: It's not quite as easy. For composite $n$, the value $\frac{1}{n^2}$ occurs fewer times than $n-1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27063/discussion-between-user118494-and-daniel-fischer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bound the variation by $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$, since $f$ attains the value $\frac{1}{n^2}$ multiple times (for $n > 2$), e.g. we have $f\bigl(\frac{1}{6}\bigr) = f\bigl(\frac{5}{6}\bigr) = \frac{1}{6^2}$. Generally, the value $\frac{1}{n^2}$ is attained at each reduced fraction with denominator $n$. A fraction $\frac{k}{n}$ is reduced if and only if $\gcd(k,n) = 1$, and the number of such $k$ not exceeding $n$ is given by Euler's totient function: $f$ attains the value $\frac{1}{n^2}$ exactly $\varphi(n)$ times.

To see that $f$ is of unbounded variation, it suffices to consider the primes. For any finite set $F$ of primes, there are partitions of $[0,1]$ such that all points $\frac{k}{p},\, 1 \leqslant k < p$ with $p\in F$ occur in the partition, and between any two successive such points there occurs an irrational partition point. Thus, for any $x\in (0,+\infty)$, there is a partition with

$$\sum \lvert \Delta f_k\rvert = 2\sum_{p \leqslant x} \frac{p-1}{p^2} \geqslant 2\sum_{p \leqslant x} \frac{1}{p} - 2\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

Since

$$\sum_{p \leqslant x} \frac{1}{p} \sim \log \log x$$

(Mertens' second theorem), we see that the variation of $f$ is unbounded.

The values $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are irrelevant, except that they need to be defined so that we have a function defined on the whole interval $[0,1]$. If a function of bounded variation is changed at finitely many points, the resulting function still has bounded variation - the value of the total variation usually changes, of course.